# Combining temp/lat/lon netcdf files via python

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, netcdf

I'm trying to combine two netcdf files into one so that my python scripts will have less I/O. The netcdf files are arranged as follows: float tasmax(time, lat, lon) and float tasmin(time, lat, lon). I want to combine these two temperature files and have one 'tasavg' netcdf file. How can I go about doing this? Let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `time` is a record dimension, you can use `ncrcat` and `ncra` from the [NCO](http://nco.sourceforge.net/) package.

```
# Combine the two files into one, along the 'time' dimension
ncrcat file1.nc file2.nc -O new_file.nc

# Average along the 'time' dimension
ncra new_file.nc -O new_file_avg.nc
```

EDIT:

This is how to accomplish what you actually asked for...

Let's say the two file names are tasmin.nc and tasmax.nc.  We need to first merge the contents of these two files into one file:

```
ncks -A tasmin.nc tasmax.nc
```

This will append the contents of tasmin.nc to tasmax.nc.  So tasmax.nc will now have the variables `tasmax` and `tasmin` inside it.

Next we need to find an average temperature by summing `tasmin` and `tasmax` and then dividing by two:

```
ncap -s "tasavg=(tasmin+tasmax)/2" tasmax.nc -O tasavg.nc
```

This will produce a new netcdf file `tasavg.nc` that will include the variables `tasmin`, `tasmax`, and `tasavg`. You can now read in `tasavg.nc` in Python and extract `tasavg` to work with further.

Comment: I tried the first step, and got the following error:                           ERROR: nco_inq_varid() reports requested variable "tasmax" is not in input file
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Short NCO-generated message (usually name of function that triggered error): nco_inq_varid()
nco_err_exit(): ERROR Error code is -49. Translation into English with nc_strerror(-49) is "NetCDF: Variable not found"
nco_err_exit(): ERROR NCO will now exit with system call exit(EXIT_FAILURE)

Comment: I misread part of your initial problem, please see my edited response.